# Macro to Insert Auto Numbering

Tags: excel, vba

I need you help for marco.

In my excel first column I would like to adding auto numbering with text in front of the text until last row.

For example:
In cell A2 (till last row) i have text "This is text", then macro should add (Result 1: This is text).

similarly in next cell

In cell A3, i have text "This is another text", then macro should add 
(Result 2: This is another text).

looking forward to your support.

thanks

Comment: Upload photo with your data please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub AddText
 Dim r as range
 Set r = range("a2") 'set pointer
 Do 'begin loop 
    r.formula = "Result " & r.row + 1 & ": " & r.text  'adjust contects
    set r = r.offset(1,0) 'move pointer
 Loop until r ="" 'keep going until blank cell
 End Sub
```